# Cat having diarrhea as medicine side effect

Tags: cats, medicines

My cat was vomiting. The doctor pushed an injection and gave Cefpodoxime oral suspension as anti biotic. But the cat is now having diarrhoea as side effect. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

give your cat food whith high quality preferably wet food and keep the water fresh and cool to be sure it drinks a lot.

when finished with the antibiotics it usually takes a week before it starts to normalize.

Comment: Should I complete the anti-biotic dose. My cat is much better but having diarrhoea as anti-biotic side effect

Comment: yes continue antibiotics for as long as the vet have said this is important to avoid the infection returning and also to avoid the bacteria to get resistant to the antibiotics.

Comment: As note, diarrhea is a very common side effect to actibiotics, as the actibiotics will also affect the bacteria in the gut.  Do not stop giving the actibiotic unless advised by the vet. Consult your vet if you're getting too concerned.